# dotnet core version number and corresponding build

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, coreclr

On dev server when i check dotnet core version number it shows

```
C:\>dotnet --version

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 1.1.0
  Build    : 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86
```

How do i find corresponding build/installation files on [dotnet core download page](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md)

I am setting up a new server and i need to make sure i have the same version of dotnet core runtime installed as dev.

Also on the same note where can i find prevision vresions on `Windows Server Hosting` for dotnet core

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: It is rather strange that `dotnet --version` does not print out similar things on my machines. From where did you install your .NET Core SDK?

Comment: @LexLi i installed it last year. I dont have the exact link but 100% sure that its from microsoft web site. Now i am trying to find the same version so i can setup my production server.

Comment: Can't you just reinstall dev with a known version that is pretty likely to be compatible anyway, test your app, and then set up production? And start taking notes of your environments.

Comment: @millimoose will i be able to use latest netcore version 1.1.1 in visual studio 2015? I heard .netcore is moving to .csproj and msbuild based instead of project.json. I cannot update to 2017 because that would require me to update all the builds.

Comment: You don't have to upgrade everything to 1.1.1, just use the latest 1.1.whatever on all environments. Make a new virtual machine, install a .NET Core version on it, try and build your project, if it works, use it everywhere.

Comment: Anything related to .NET Core SDK last year is preview. The first official release (RTM) of .NET Core Tooling (SDK) was released on March 7, 2017. You have to upgrade to Visual Studio 2017, or at least update the SDK installation to its 1.0 release. Please avoid using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I added http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net-core/9592/components-and-versioning-in-net-core some time ago. Does any of that help?

Comment: You will find all the old versions here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/archives

Answer (score 0):

Just search for the [tags](https://github.com/dotnet/core/tags) or [releases](https://github.com/dotnet/core/releases) inside the .Net Core Github repo or on the [archives site](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core) on Microsoft.

But you should really upgrade to a version that is not end of life.